# Conditional sails model schemas

Tags: orm, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying write a conditional model schema based if exists other models.

For example, if exist model 'Message' then add a inbox/outbox:

```js
var userSchema = {
    attributes: {
    ...
    }
}

var messageSchema = {
    attributes: {
        inbox: {
            collection: 'Message'
             },
        outbox: {
            collection: 'Message'
             }
    }
};


if (<function to check that Message Model is available)
    _.merge userSchema, messageSchema
```

Is it possible do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need one "pre model load" fase on plugins and one hook to alow others modules do alter it structure like **drupal 7** scheme.

You cold exports one function to plug this "fase feature" in plugin npm loader like i did with default configs: https://github.com/wejs/we-plugin/blob/master/lib/index.js#L18 and set in https://github.com/wejs/we-example/blob/master/app.js#L63